# Create a link in javascript popup

Tags: javascript, html

I would think this is very easy but I have searched and searched and can't find a solution. I have setup an over 18 age verify popup using this code I found.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Website-Age-Verification-Plugin-with-jQuery.html

The code and popup work great. BUT, If someone clicks "no" and you get the regret response, it then says like click to leave, and when you click the overlay just goes away and you are on the site.

I would like that if when you click "no" it to say "sorry, click here to leave" and when you click it actually takes you somewhere else, any link, like google.com

The js file has a link url in the regret code to #nothing . When i change that to an actual link it still doesn't work as I intend.

Is that clearly stated? My first time here and want to explain it all. The site this is being setup on is kickbassvapor.com if you want to see it. The files and a demo are at the link above.

Thank you in advance!

ETA: sorry here is the code in question.

```
// Regret Content
var regret_heading = $('<h2>We\'re Sorry!</h2>');
var regret_buttons = $('<nav><small>I hit the wrong button!</small> <ul><li><a href="#nothing" class="av_btn av_go" rel="yes">I\'m old enough!</a></li></ul></nav');
var regret_text = $('<p>You must be 21 years of age or older to enter this site.</p>');

modal_content_wrapper.append(content_heading, content_buttons, content_text);
modal_regret_wrapper.append(regret_heading, regret_buttons, regret_text);
modal_content.append(modal_content_wrapper, modal_regret_wrapper);
```

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of the code that shows the problem here and not from some third party site that can change or disappear tomorrow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank Rob, post updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file age-verification.js in line 69 change:

```
av_showRegret();
```

to:

```
window.location.href = "http://google.com";
```